# import and call function within Method not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating a small VueJs app, that calls the NASA image API and displays on the screen.

In the Header component (below) I have a search bar, when clicked this will call the Axios method defined in another file,  I understood from the documents that if import functions to component then they need to be defined in the 'methods'. However, when I click search nothing displays on the console?

note: the call to NASA has been tested and does work when I include in the component. Which I guess begs the question if I should leave it in the component as I won't use it elsewhere.

but would still like to understand the logic behind the issue.

component code:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Nasa Image Search</h1>

    <div class="search-container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" />
        <button v-on:click="search" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import nasa from '../apiCall'

export default {
  name: 'Header',
  methods: {
    search : function(){
      nasa
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Axios function call:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const nasa = () => {
  var url = `https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=apollo-13&media_type=image`
  console.log(url) //bug testing

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.error(error)
    })
}

export default { nasa }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default export is actually an object with a function property, like this:

```js
{
  nasa: () => { ... }
}
```

When you import the object, you give it the name `nasa`, so you'd actually have to call the function like:

```js
nasa.nasa()
```

Since you probably intend to just export the function, leave your import as is but change your export to:

```js
export default nasa;  // no brackets
```

And in your component, you don't need to embed that in a method, you can set it directly to the `search` method:

```js
methods: {
  search: nasa
}
```